# Are my one-method (and a couple attribute) classes overkill?

Tags: python, classes

I saw a talk by Jack Diederich a few weeks ago titled "[Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)" and noticed that some of my code perhaps echoes what he argues against (to the effect of "classes with two methods, one of which is `__init__`") in my code. For some parser that needed to run through a bunch of data, I created a couple classes that implement a single method to extract the salient information and tack it on to the end.

```
class DataFrameBuilder(object):
    column_order = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def render(self):
        return pd.DataFrame(self.data, columns=self.column_order)

class BoundsBuilder(DataFrameBuilder):
    data_type = 'bounds'
    column_order = ['bid', 'x_min', 'x_max', 'y_min', 'y_max']

    def append(self, bid, blob):
        centroid_x, centroid_y = zip(*blob['centroid'])
        self.data.append({'bid': bid,
                'x_min': min(centroid_x), 'x_max': max(centroid_x),
                'y_min': min(centroid_y), 'y_max': max(centroid_y),
            })
...

def summarize(experiment):
    builders = [BoundsBuilder(), TerminalsBuilder(), SizeBuilder()]

    for bid, blob in experiment.blobs():
        for builder in builders:
            builder.append(bid, blob)

    return {builder.data_type: builder.render() for builder in builders}
```

I could do the same thing with a couple of dictionaries to store my results and attributes, along with bare functions I pass said dictionary (or value within it), it might even be a few less lines, so I don't know if I'm over-using classes here or not.

My example here is fairly small, but that's why it's here, because they are my smallest classes and perhaps on the edge of usefulness/overkill.

Comment: What does this code intend to accomplish?

Comment: It creates multiple data frames with one row per "blob" and puts them in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - in this case classes are an overkill.

Think of classes as nouns, and methods as verbs. Functions do things, while classes are those actual things.

For instance - compare `DataFrameBuilder` (noun) with `build_data_frame` (verb). Which makes more sense? Which describes the business logic better? I think the second, since the focus here on **building** data, and not on a **builder** itself.

I think I picked up the idea from Steve Yegge's post ["Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns"](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) (great article, you should read it when you have time).

Answer (score 1):

Because your inheriting that method into another class, I don't think you are quite hitting the example he was talking about. As it is, your class allows me to `append`, `render`, get a `column_order` and a `data_type`. So its not simply a disguised function.

It does suffer from some complexity bloat. Why do you accumulate your output instead of just taking an iterable input and return the result? Why use inheritance rather than composition?

Let's consider your code rewritten without classes:

```
def render_bounds(bid, blob):
    centroid_x, centroid_y = zip(*blob['centroid'])
    return {'bid': bid,
        'x_min': min(centroid_x), 'x_max': max(centroid_x),
        'y_min': min(centroid_y), 'y_max': max(centroid_y),
    }

def render_blobs(renderer, blobs):
    return [renderer(bid, blob) for bid, blob in blobs]

def summarize(experiment):
    return {
        'bounds': render_blobs(render_bounds, experiment.blobs),
        'terminals': render_blobs(render_terminals, experiment.blobs),
        'size': render_blobs(render_size, experiment.blobs)
    }
```

I think this is more straightforward then your class-based code. But I have lost `column_order`, as your code didn't actually use it. I've also moved the data_type attribute away from the functions which define them. I've also lost the ability to compose Builders to produce things. All of these things introduce trade-offs which may or may not make sense in the scope of your design.

Comment: `column_order`'s use is hidden in the `render()` method. A major design/performance goal was to avoid independently creating and iterating through `experiment.blobs()` which is rather slow (it reads from several hundreds of MB of files). I was trying to figure out how to use `itertools.tee`, but like in your example I couldn't figure out how to use them in parallel to avoid necessarily keeping all the data in memory (basically just a massive space/speed trade-off).

Comment: @NickT, in that case I'd your solution is pretty reasonable. `itertools.tee` is kinda useless because its near impossible to consume the produced iterables in parallel. If you have to do similiar operations a lot, then I'd look into abstract some common patterns, but until then I'd 100% say you aren't overusing classes here.